# jsTree open_all not firing all the time

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I get x number of projects and their related directory structure from the server in one AJAX call, then it disconnects from the server. Now all operation should work from the browser.

Now the projects loaded in a Listbox and jsTree should load its associated data onChange event. Everything works fine, but jsTree's open_all works only for the first Listbox click. After that it collapse.

This is my code.

```
function Refresh(item) {
    $('#MainTree').bind("loaded.jstree", function (e, data) {
        $('#MainTree').jstree("open_all"); //WORKS FINE
        //data.inst.open_all(-1); //WORKS FINE
    }).jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "data": [item]
        },
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "dots": true,
            "icons": true
        },
        "ui": {
            "select_limit": 1
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "types"]
    });
}
```

And below is my HTML button code, for collapse & open which also works fine.  Any idea?

```
<input type="button" value="Collapse All" onclick="$('#MainTree').jstree('close_all');">
<input type="button" value="Expand All" onclick="$('#MainTree').jstree('open_all');">
```

Answer (score 0):

After few days of try, I gave up this one and tried [TreeTable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/index.html) plugin and it worked perfect.

Hope this helps someone.